# Preventing banging class into class into class so they pipeline for cleaner code

Tags: python, class

I have two classes in Python:

```
from docx import Document
from docx2pdf import convert

class WordFill():
    def __init__(self, certNum)
        self.certNum = certNum

        docFields = {
            'certNum': str(certNum),
        }

        doc = Document('certTemplate.docx')

        for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
            for key in docFields:
                paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key, docFields[key])
        doc.save(f'{certNum}.docx')
        
    def create_cert(self):
        return str(f'{self.certNum}.docx')
```

This basically replaces numbers in a word file.

I then have another class:

```
class DocToPdf():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        
        convert(filename)
        os.unlink(filename)
```

So to instantiate, I pass the following:

```
DoctoPDF(WordFill(certNum=1234).create_cert()
)
```

Now to get the return from the first class, the class method has to be invoked because on `__init__` return is none. To feed that result into the second class, it becomes second class on outside taking filename from the return of the first cass method `create_cert()` return statement.

Is this the correct way of doing it? because a lot of time the code in classes looks way more clean and neat and almost like they can operate separately etc. I am not sure I am on the best track for nesting classes like that in that way.

Any advice from those more experienced?

Comment: Why are these classes? (EDIT: IOW, I'd make them plain functions.)

Comment: Largely a matter of taste. Personally, I wouldn't mind. Most programmers would probably use a local variable to capture the return value of `create_cert()`.

Comment: This is more suitable for `CodeReview`. That said there is a lot that can be improved

Comment: For those comments done so far. It is more trying to check if my understanding of how to get classes to work together is on the correct track or not. Cheers for the code review hint, I think that really is a better place for something more theortical.

Comment: Since this isn't really valid as an answer (since this is opinion-based and would belong on Code Review), here's what I'd do as a gist – just plain functions: https://gist.github.com/akx/e7d085fcdd03d1943a896b399c439990

Comment: AKX cheers for the link. That is the main thing structure wise I did, but more interested into the way classes work. Thank you for your time and cheers for a great example. buran, Cheers for the advice. @Friedrich, thank you for a stir in the correct direction and reality of things.

Comment: For codereview, please excuse my miss understanding in advance. That would be just changing the tags when asking a question? I would like to be more aware of how to approach the platform without wasting people's time.

Comment: What is `DocToPdf()` accepted a class rather than a filename?

Comment: Code reviews have a site of their own: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jonSG, `DocToPdf()` is a python library in itself to convert word documents to pdf, I implemented in a class that as input takes the output of the class that creates the word documents. So the class method in `WordFill()` gives filename that was generated and to be converted.

Friedrich, thanks, will check it out.